# Cannot find package "internal/cpu" error in GO

Tags: go

Go as an internal package [internal/cpu](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/internal/cpu/cpu.go#L15:L32) that exposes all the necessary functions to detect flavors of SIMD. 
See an example of use in the [bytes package](https://github.com/golang/go/blob/master/src/bytes/bytes_amd64.go#L19).

I'm trying to get capability flags variables from `internal/cpu` package but when i'm trying to execute go build, i'm getting following error: `cannot find package "internal/cpu`

```
import (
    "fmt"
    "internal/cpu"
)

func main() {
    if cpu.X86.HasAVX2 {
        fmt.Println("AVX2 SIMD instructions available")
    }
}
```

What i did wrong?

Comment: It's called "internal" for a reason. You cannot import some other project's `internal`s.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will not be able to import `internal/cpu` due to this rule:

> Code in or below a directory named "internal" is importable only by code in the directory tree rooted at the parent of "internal".

https://golang.org/cmd/go/#hdr-Internal_Directories

You can copy out the parts of the code you need, just make sure to follow the LICENSE, which is fairly open:

https://golang.org/LICENSE

Answer (score 0):

I know that's an old topic but I was trying to do the same thing today and I found this post. So, here's how I solved it:

```
package main

import (
    "fmt"

    "golang.org/x/sys/cpu"
)

func main() {

    if cpu.X86.HasAVX {
        fmt.Println("AVX: true")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("AVX: false")
    }

    if cpu.X86.HasAVX2 {
        fmt.Println("AVX2: true")
    } else {
        fmt.Println("AVX2: false")
    }

}
```

The output on my old machine with i7-4820K CPU looks like that:

```
AVX: true
AVX2: false
```